# ajax.click function is not loading relevant page, button is not working at all

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi before I put my code in im just going to briefly explain what im trying to do. I have a "live search" page where if a user types "A" all results that have an A in it are shown and if "AB" then all that have AB.

What I have done is made buttons appear next to each result so that when I click a particular one, another page is run and something appears on the right hand side. I'm trying to do this through ajax but it just is not working! Eventually, on the right hand side i'll have data from my sql database but for now im just trying to display basic html. Could someone help please?

the live search page:

```
<form name="searching" method="post">
    Search<input type="text" name="search" OnKeyUp="dynamicSearch();">
    <div id="sResults"></div>
</form>
```

Beneath this I have my "dynamicSearch" script which is just the xmlhttp request which gets my searchCars.php and displays data.

The searchCars.php page (where the ajax script will be).

```
echo "<input type='button' class='viewbutton'>" . $row['carName'] . "</a>";
<div id="rightdiv" style="width: 60%; float:right">
</div>
```

Above this button I have my SELECT * statements and that's all.

Ajax script on this page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".viewbutton").each(function(){
 var btn = $(this);

 btn.on("click",function(){
 $("#rightdiv").empty();
 $.post("test.php",
 function(data) {
      $("#rightdiv").append(data);
    }
    );
 });
 });
 });
```

All that test.php contains is:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>test</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Can you console.log(data) right before appending it and tell me what it says?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute

Comment: Remember to set your datatype.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: The console.log, GETS the searchcars.php, but clicking the button does nothing...nothing appears in console log either

Comment: please describe the problem in the title

Answer (score 0):

Right now it looks like you are trying to loop through each button that is appended and put a click function on each. However, you do not need to do this, and this is where your issue could reside. The way do accomplish what you want to accomplish can work like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".viewbutton").click(function(){
         //Put your ajax here
    });
});
```

Example: http://pastebin.com/U029bDed

Comment: I just tried this but no difference. The console log does not seem to register the "button" at all? Clicking it does nothing at all

Comment: Can you start with this, just put an `alert()` inside the click.function() and see if it does that?

Comment: Nope, nothing happened

Comment: Alright, I am assuming you included the jquery files and that they are included before the ajax script?

Comment: yep i have a <head> tag at the top

Comment: okay, are you using chrome? can you check the sources to make sure that your JS got included and see if it has any errors inside?

Comment: Using firefox, just going to try on chrome now

Comment: I would check the inspect element, make sure the buttons have the correct class and check on the sources tab to make sure that your js was included and has no errors. Also I guess I didn't put a document.ready function in my code, you might need that, so I edited my code.

Comment: Ok, I just ran on chrome. Not entirely sure what you mean by comment above (apologies, new to this). But I inspected the "button" i have beside each result and it just leads to <input type="button" class="viewbutton". I can see my javascript below on the same page..

Comment: Alright, try putting your JS in the head below the jQuery includes

Comment: Just tried that still nothing. The button just does not seem to get recognized, clicking it has no effect, no code or anything is run?..

Comment: Is the jquery included on the searchcars.php page? or is it on the live search page? And is that the same page where the buttons appear according to the browser?

Comment: jquery is included on searchcars.php page. According to browser, buttons appear on search.php (where the live search is). I just tried your pastebin example. My code is basically the same, but button does not seem to work. I think there could be a problem with my ajax code..

Comment: If your buttons are on the search.php page you need to have your jquery on the same page(search.php) instead of searchcars.php.

Comment: tried it, does nothing :( i'm so stuck have no idea what to do now

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

```
echo "<input type='button' class='viewbutton'>" . $row['carName'] . "</a>";
```

`<input>` isn't closed (like `<input />` or `</input>`) and there's some unpaired `</a>` there. Something's wrong here, either:

- You have opened that `<a>` somewhere before that code and you have `<input>` wrapped in `<a>`, or
- It was an `<a>` before, but you have partially changed it to `<input>`

Anyway, your browser is trying to fix the markup and messes it up even more. As a final result, there's no `.viewbutton` element to bind event to or it's not the element you expect.

I would try something like this:

```
echo "<button type='button' class='viewbutton'>" . $row['carName'] . "</button>";
```

Comment: The results all appear as buttons, however on clicking them the console log shows nothing, so they're still not getting recognized at all..

Comment: Are you sure that the element already exists when you bind the event? Isn't it inserted into DOM later? Make sure you do the binding when DOM is loaded or when element is inserted.